# I'm in need of guidance for apettite control

Tags: weight-loss

I'm 340lbs and I'm 5'10" and I'm trying to lose some weight. I'm currently watching my calorie intake during the day, but as soon as I end my exercise routine or its around 10pm to 12pm, I feel like I'm starving! I do take a lot of water to try to control it, but it doesn't seem enough. I'm really, really, really holding myself from eating too much at night. Is there any type of food that will control this?

Comment: Vegetables vegetables vegetables.  It is not humanly possible to consume enough broccoli to maintain body weight at your size :)

Comment: Do you feel this is your stomach being empty or your blood sugar being low? (I second Affes call for vegetables and would like to throw in oats -- high fiber is usually good.)

Comment: stomach being empty, but will try suggestion... Will let you know tomorrow. Thank you both...btw do you know any person that have myFitnesPal so it can help me to get more motivated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Affe said, eating more vegetable will help. Short of that, any sort of caffeine-based drink--coffee, tea, etc.-- can serve as an appetite suppressant, too.

Answer (score 0):

What I have had to do to keep my appetite in control is to "shrink my stomach". You see, before I started dieting I would eat no breakfast, a light lunch and then gorge in the evening for dinner about 1 or 2 hours before bed. The food would just sit and turn to fat as I slept. My stomach got to where it would not feel full unless I was overeating.

To solve this I started fasting.  First I say only do this if you have no medical issues and you will not be doing any intense physical work while you fast. Also stop if at anytime your uncomfortable.

To start eat light for a couple of days and then try going 24 hours without eating. Then eat light for a week and try going 36-48 hours without eating. You don't want to go over 3 days for safety. Each time you do this you will notice that when you do eat it will not take less to fill yourself up. I looked into this after having the flu for a week and going ~3days without eating.

Work up to fasting once every 2 weeks and begin light working out and see how you feel. Your body will have nothing left to burn but your body fat.

Comment: Personal experience is good but your answer will be better if you back this up with some references.

Comment: This seems dangerous!